# Google Drive .NET API version 2 DLL

Tags: google-drive-api

Google has an example using the Google Drive .NET version 2 library:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#examples

I can't find the place to download the DLL to my system.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: can you answer this question too?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591393/google-apis-different-versions

Comment: any comment on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591393/google-apis-different-versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new dlls will be available very soon on http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API

Comment: I assume that you can't tell me an exact date, but do you have an idea when it will be out? (basically either a few days or a few weeks?). I have the option to freeze my development if it is a few days. If it won't be out until a few weeks I'd rather continue using the Google Docs API 2.1. Thanks.

Comment: It should be out next week, but take into account the holidays for the 4th of July, so it might slip to the week of July 9th

Comment: If you are really desperate to do some testing, I can get you an *unofficial* build in the meantime.

Comment: I would be happy to work with the *unofficial* one meanwhile.

Comment: The dlls for Drive v2 are now available at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API