# Google APIs - Different Versions

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-drive-api, google-tasks

I am using Google Tasks API V1 dot net libraries.  In the same project I also want to use Google Drive, Contacts and Calendar APIs.  Drive, Contacts and Calendar APIs are V2.  Now the issue I am facing is that Google Tasks .Net libraries and Google Drive/Calendar .Net libraries do not work together.  Visual Studio would not compile (error: these libraries are linked to different versions of Google.apis.dll).  I tried finding Tasks API libraries V2, but it does not exist. Then I tried finding libraries for Drive or Calendar V1, but couldn't find them either.  This is forcing me to use GData libraries (and API) for Calendar, Contacts and Drive.  The problem is GData API is deprecated and will go away in 2015.

I must be missing something here because I can't imagine Google guys could bungle up this big.

Comment: Welcome to DLL Hell, population: you.

Comment: In addition, the API are so poorly documented and details are spread over hundreds of different places. Many examples given on these fragmented document pages are technically wrong.  I believe this company Google is so much hype. Their engineers have bloated egos and tiny brains.  I am really mad because I have spent tens of hours researching this with no end at sight.  With GData API, I finally made Calendar entries working but the API doesn't support time zones. No matter how you format time, it always end up in GMT in the calendar.  I have to employ a hack on my side to overcome this.

Comment: No they are not third party libraries.  All from Google.

Comment: Does anyone know any third party dot.net libraries for Google Tasks, Calendar, Contacts and Drive APIs?